# Why we use public and private variable separately

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
  var Command = function () {
      var _self = this,

       //flag to indicate that the operation is running
       _isRunning = ko.observable(false),

        //property to save the error message
       _errorMessage = ko.observable();

       //public properties
        this.isRunning = _isRunning;
        this.errorMessage = _errorMessage;
 };
```

Why does this example use both private and public variables? Is this a design pattern we are following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In just the code you've quoted, there's no reason. But my guess is that later in that outermost function, you have something like this:

```
this.doSomething = function() {
    if (_isRunning()) {
        // do one thing
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
};
```

The reason for having the local variables is so that it doesn't matter what `this` value the function is called with.

That said, the `_self` variable already solves that problem for you just as well, making the `_isRunning` and `_errorMessage` variables purely convenience aliases. The above could just as well be:

```
this.doSomething = function() {
    if (_self.isRunning()) {
        // do one thing
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
};
```

There's no particular design pattern here, it's just using the fact that functions created within other functions are closures over the local variables (and a few other things) of the function they're created in.